# Multiple iteration rounds of os.walk() doesn't seem to work - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

It seems like os.walk only executes once even if it's inside of a loop. For example here is a code i was testing out.

```
for num in range(5):
    count = 0
    for path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
        count += 1

    print(count)
```

os.walk seems to work only once, and then ignores any further iteration because the output I get is:

```
3
1
1
1
1
```

I was expecting to see the number 3 for each of the 5 runs. Why did this not work?

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning `path` in the second for loop

Answer (score 1):

You reassign `path` on every iteration of your inner loop, walking down the structure of your original path.  When you get to a leaf node, you *keep* that value of `path`, and then go to the next iteration of your 5, but starting at the leaf node.

Don't mess with your loop parameters!  Instead, make the original path independent of your iteration:

```
start_point = '/'

for num in range(5):
    count = 0
    for path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(start_point):
        count += 1

    print(count)
```

For future peace of mind, see this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  Simply adding `print path` in one or two well-chosen spots would have shown you what goes wrong.